# Adding information to layers in group (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

For a QGIS plugin I want to access the layers in a group called 'Drawings'. For this I want a ComboBox with the list of layers. I tried different methods but can't get past the fact that i am refering to a list. For now this is my code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeGroup

# Fetch the currently loaded layers
layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()

# Access Drawings group and add the childeren to a ComboBox
group = layers.children(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Drawings'))
self.dlg.CB_newlanduselayer.addItems(group)
```

Anyone a clue how to enhance this code so i can get a list of the layers in 'Drawings'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
# Get group
group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('Drawings')
# Iterate group to get list of layer names
layers = [layer.name() for layer in group.children()]
```